spring-integration header unwrap issue
I upgraded my spring-integration version 1.5.4 to spring-integration-core 6.3.4 after that I am facing a header issue in routeToRecipients, so whenever I want to reach header info in here the message object converting just an OrderMessage and naturally, I get casting exception. Btw my message broker is rabbitmq I couldnt find any clear explanation in documents or migration document  enter link description here
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow orderRequestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(ORDER_CHANNEL)
            .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".orderChannel")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "orderChannel"))
            .<byte[]>handle((message, responseHeaders) -> {
                OrderMessage orderMessage = (OrderMessage) jsonMessageConverter.convert(message);
                Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(orderMessage) 
                        .copyHeaders(responseHeaders)
                        .build();

                return m;
            })
            .routeToRecipients(exhaustedRetriesRouter -> exhaustedRetriesRouter
                    .recipient(GenericFlow.EXHAUSTED_CHANNEL,
                            message ->
                            //the message just OrderMessage type, unwrap Message type
                                   ((Message<?>) message).getHeaders().containsKey("x-death")
                                            &&((Long) ((Map<?, ?>) ((List<?>) ((Message<?>) message).getHeaders().get("x-death")).get(0)).get("count") >= 3L))


That's correct. The recipient() contract is:
public <P> RecipientListRouterSpec recipient(String channelName, GenericSelector<P> selector) {

Where that GenericSelector is instantiated from your lambda. And since Java has generics erasure, there is no way to determine that you would expect the whole Message. And framework assumption that in most cases just a payload is expected in the end-user code.
For that purpose we have another API:
public RecipientListRouterSpec recipientMessageSelector(String channelName, MessageSelector selector) {

Where contact of the MessageSelector is :
boolean accept(Message<?> message);

So, no any generics, not erasure and the framework knows that the whole Message is expected in the target lambda.

Thanks for your answer @Artem. I realized that when I checked source code.
Here is the implementation in old version (spring-integration-java-dsl 1.2.3) and that changed with latest one.
public RecipientListRouterSpec recipient(String channelName, MessageSelector selector) {   return recipient(channelName, (GenericSelector<Message<?>>) selector);  }

Right. Newer Java complains that it cannot determine which method to use for provided lambda. Therefore we had to extract a new recipientMessageSelector to satisfy target simple lambda without extra casting on end-user side.

Hi Artem, I apricated your answer. I asked another question IMO, it wasnt same question. With new version I cant get directly Message object anymore. The object was converted LınkedHashMap. So I had to add a handle for recreate same message. I want to avoid that. Am I missing something? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79138118/spring-integration-message-type-issue]

I suggest to create a new SO question with the specific part about JSON. Right now it fully looks like the same about recipient list router concern. That is too old out of support version to dig.

I will create a new question, thanks. But in my original code this part doesn't exist, and in that situation I receive a hashmaplist not an object, so I added <>handle part I think that is not related json.
`.<byte[]>handle((message, responseHeaders) -> {
OrderMessage orderMessage = (OrderMessage) jsonMessageConverter.convert(message);
Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(orderMessage)
.copyHeaders(responseHeaders)
.build();
            return m;
        })`


Looks like you are converting there from byte[] to something what JsonMessageConverter could do for you. So, that is really related to JSON deserialization. You might deal in your router before just with byte[]. Essentially, ignored that payload at all. So, right now see if migrating to the recipientMessageSelector would let you to eliminate that handle()  again. According to your current logic just against headers it does not matter if you convert from those byte[] or not.
