spring-integration message type issue
I upgraded my spring-integration-java-dsl 1.2.3 to spring-integration-core 6.3.4 after that I am facing data type issue, Whenever I try to reach the message object, that is converting just an byte[] and naturally, I get casting exception. But before upgrade the dependency old imp was working without convert step. So I refactored to my implementation like bellow but I am not sure that is the best way because I need to refactor all my Integrationflows. So Is there any setting or something else to avoid code changes?
Old Implementation
    public IntegrationFlow orderRequestFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ORDER_CHANNEL)
                .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".orderChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "orderChannel"))
                .routeToRecipients(exhaustedRetriesRouter -> exhaustedRetriesRouter
                        .recipient(GenericFlow.EXHAUSTED_CHANNEL,
                               //the message just byte[]
                                message -> message.getHeaders().containsKey("x-death") 

New Implementation
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orderRequestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(ORDER_CHANNEL)
            .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".orderChannel")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "orderChannel"))
            .<byte[]>handle((message, responseHeaders) -> {
                OrderMessage orderMessage = (OrderMessage) jsonMessageConverter.convert(message);
                Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(orderMessage) 
                        .copyHeaders(responseHeaders)
                        .build();

                return m;
            })
            .routeToRecipients(exhaustedRetriesRouter -> exhaustedRetriesRouter
                    .recipient(GenericFlow.EXHAUSTED_CHANNEL,
                            message ->
                            
                                   ((Message<?>) message).getHeaders().containsKey("x-death")


That's a pretty big bump from libraries/versions. I would recommend going through the change logs of spring-integration-core 6.3.4 down to see if there is some info on this problem https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/releases
